# Received Field is Empty when the Size is Big in Spring Boot Post Method

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I tried to send a string via POST method to a SpringBoot webserver, when string is small (200k), it could be received at the controller end, whereas when string is relatively big (2M), the controller's field is empty without any error message in springBoot log.

The controller code snippet is:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/func")
public ResponseMessage func(@RequestParam(value = "message", defaultValue = "") String message) {
    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(message))    {
        // alert
    }
}
```

and the Sender's code snippet is:

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
// Create socket configuration
SocketConfig socketConfig = SocketConfig.custom().setSoKeepAlive(true)
        .setSoTimeout(180000).setSoReuseAddress(true).setTcpNoDelay(true).build();

// Configure the connection manager to use socket configuration either
// by default or for a specific host.
connManager.setDefaultSocketConfig(socketConfig);
// Validate connections after 1 minute of inactivity
connManager.setValidateAfterInactivity(180000);
connManager.setMaxTotal(100);
connManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);

// Create global request configuration
RequestConfig defaultRequestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.DEFAULT).setExpectContinueEnabled(true)
        .setConnectTimeout(180000).setSocketTimeout(180000)
        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(180000).build();

CloseableHttpClient hc = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(connManager)
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(defaultRequestConfig).setDefaultSocketConfig(socketConfig)
        .build();


String encodedMsg = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(args[0])), UTF_8);
UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(Lists.newArrayList(new BasicNameValuePair("message", encodedMsg)), UTF_8);
HttpUriRequest httpPost = HttpUtils.post("http://url/func", entity);

try (CloseableHttpResponse response = hc.execute(httpPost)) {
    // ...
}
```

I've tried to add the following request-body-size parameteres in application.properties but it seems not working. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
multipart.maxRequestSize=30MB
multipart.maxFileSize=30MB
spring.http.multipart.maxFileSize=30Mb
spring.http.multipart.maxRequestSize=30Mb
```

**SpringBoot: 1.5.10.RELEASE**

**Spring: 4.3.14.RELEASE**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2MB are default max size for Post request parameter in tomcat.
Assuming that you are using tomcat, max post size limit can be turned off by
setting

```
server.tomcat.max-http-post-size=-1
```

Comment: yep I'm using spring boot and embedded tomcat. so I just put the above param in application.properties?

Comment: yeah it's working now. for reference, parameters regarding embedded tomcat could be found here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html